# Install and use LISP on Mac

Tags: emacs, lisp, xlispstat

I've read many topics regarding this issue, but couldn't get it to an end. I want to be able to code in LISP on Mac, using Emacs and XLispStat.
So far, I've installed Emacs with HomeBrew but I got stuck when installing XLispStat. Can someone detail the steps for doing this? I'll appreciate!

P.S.: This is the required installation for Lisp. If there is something easier to achieve on Mac, I'll try that as well!

Comment: `port install emacs slime sbcl`

Comment: What do you mean by "got stuck"?

Comment: The best rated emacs port for the Mac seems to be http://emacsformacosx.com.

Comment: @uselpa: I don't know how to install XLispStat. There are some commands in the INSTALL file, but I'm far from being a guru in command lines :)

Comment: @SK-logic: Can you further explain that command? :)

Comment: I've installed Emacs from your supplied URL, but how to run LISP code? :)

Comment: @linkyndy, it's a way to go with MacPorts. This command will install you everything you'd ever need for using Common Lisp. If you're on a HomeBrew, look for an equivalent. But I did not notice that you want XLispStat (and therefore, xlisp). It's pretty dead by now. Why would you want using it instead of, say, R? But, if you insist, follow this instructions: ftp://ftp.stat.umn.edu/pub/xlispstat/current/macintosh/README.MAC_OS_X

Comment: I would be surprised if XLispStat runs in a useful way on a Intel Mac running Mac OS X 10.8.

Comment: My best advice is to listen to the advice of others-- in particular, SK-logic and Rainer.  They both make good points regarding this question and on questions in general.  If you really want to try to compile XLispStat for OS X, however, [this page](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~rend0020/computing/index.html) might help.  At the very least, there are some comments there that might hint at what you are up against.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I've just managed to build X11 version of XLisp on Mac, with a bit of tweaks in the code. But still can't see how could it be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. The reason why I need XLispStat is that it is required by my university, but since it is outdated, I'll go with some other options. You are saying Emacs + Slime, right? Oh, and is there a possibility to write the code is some normal text editor and compile it somehow in the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a similar answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9608810/190887). Short version: your options for an OS X Lisp environment are [LispBox](http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/), [LispWorks personal](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/index.html) (crippleware warning) or Emacs+SLIME via [quicklisp](https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-slime-helper/blob/master/README.txt)/[ELPA](http://tromey.com/elpa/install.html).

Since your comments imply that you're casting a pretty wide net for workable Common Lisp tools, I'll also mention that [CLISP](http://www.clisp.org/) seems to be supported via various OS X ports/package managers and has a fairly comfortable REPL (you can, of course get the same in [SBCL with Linedit](http://common-lisp.net/project/linedit/)).

EDIT: As Rainer and Vsevolod mention below, [Clozure](http://ccl.clozure.com/download.html) and [MCLIDE](http://mclide.com/) also exist. I've used neither myself, so I can't give you any details (though Clozure has been recommended to me on multiple occasions).

> Oh, and is there a possibility to write the code is some normal text editor and compile it somehow in the terminal?

Not in the way that I think you mean, but yes, you can write a `.lisp` file with Sublime or whatever, then `sbcl your-file-here.lisp`. Note that `sbcl your-file-here.lisp` starts a running Lisp instance with a REPL, and incurs all the overhead that implies. If you're dead set against Emacs, what you could do is run a REPL separately from your project directory, then just `(load "file-you-changed.lisp")` or `(ql:quickload :your-project-name)` every so often.

Comment: I've gone with Emacs+Slime, as it is the closest alternative to what I'm demanded. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

xlispstat can be compiled on Mac OS 10.8 and works perfectly fine. It needs a couple of little edits for the nitpicking compiler but works perfectly with XQuartz. The people who are telling you to use other systems don't know how well integrated xlispstat is for people doing numerical work.

Comment: @SK-logic: Not to start a flamewar or anything, just as a matter of opinion: For anyone with a mathematical bent, lisp is much easier to use than R. I've never figured out how Tierney could give up on xlisp and go work on R. Different strokes ...